# Developing Library for a Blackberry 10 app

Tags: static-libraries, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I want to develop a Authentication library for Blackberry 10 app. This will contain some UI elements and request/response handling to the server for authentication purpose.

I have come to know that there are static(.a) and dynamic(.so) libraries that can be created.

I want to make a static library for my purpose.

Can anyone enlighten me how to create a static library using QNX Momentics IDE and How can I include this library into my app project?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wizard for doing this. File -> New -> BlackBerry Project. Select Library then Static then click Next ...

Answer (score 0):

Add Libraries by clicking Project -> Add Library in the Momentics IDE. Momentics comes with s wealth of libraries already pre-installed with it. You may also choose to install an external library from your workspace or elsewhere on your disk